# Puzzled with constraints routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning `rails`.And here are some questions I can't understand.

```
class NamespaceConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    name = request.fullpath.split('/').second.downcase
    if name[0] == '~' then name = name[1..-1] end
    ns = Namespace.where(name_lower: request.fullpath.split('/').second.downcase).first
    not ns.nil?
  end
end


Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraints(NamespaceConstraint) do
    get  ':namespace' => 'namespaces#show'
  end
end
```

- What does these codes mean?
- In `self.matches?`. `?`means what?
- This `request` var wasn't defined，is `rails` creates it?
- `not ns.nil?`  This means what?

I am a complete beginner to ruby.
Thanks for helping me solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In self.matches?. `?` means what?

In Ruby you can use far more characters then in most other languages when naming methods.

Among those are `?` and `!`. They have no special meaning to the interpreter.

However the convention in the community is that methods ending in `?` are *interrogative*. They tell you if something is true or false.

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :age

  def initialize(age = 0)
    @age = age
  end

  def drinking_age?
    @age >= 18
  end
end
```

> This request var wasn't defined，is rails creates it?

`request` in this context is a method argument.

Inside the `.matches?` method the local variable `request` is whatever you have passed into the method.

Rails calls something like `NamespaceConstraint.matches?(request)`* when it checks if the incoming request matches your custom constraint.

The `request` object is created by the Rack middleware.

> not ns.nil?

`not` is keyword that negates the following expression. Just like in english. `!` is more commonly used due to precedence.

`nil` in ruby is nothing - a value that is not defined or has no value.

So `.nil?` tells you if a variable is nil. Every object in ruby responds to this method.

```
irb(main):007:0> 0.nil?
=> false
irb(main):008:0> false.nil?
=> false
irb(main):009:0> nil.nil?
=> true
```

So `not ns.nil?` translates to plain english as:  `is ns not nothing?` or `is ns anything?`.

### Conclusion

You're really out of you're depth. The only reason you would do something like 
this is if you where building a multi-tenant app - which is a hardly a task
suited for a beginner.

First learn the basics of the Ruby language.

- [Try Ruby](http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0)
- [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/ruby)
- [Programming Ruby - The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)

Then revisit Rails. Learning both a programming language and a framework at the same time is not a really good idea as you will mush both together mentally.

Comment: Thanks a lot.One more question:`ns` is the data selected from `Namespace`.So `not ns.nil?` just means `false` or `true`.Is the `matches?` return a value when be called.Or the `NamespaceConstraint` return something in `constraints(NamespaceConstraint)`.I am still worried with       `constraints(NamespaceConstraint) do get  ':namespace' =>  'namespaces#show' end`

Comment: You won't be able to understand that code anyways without a basic understanding of ruby. So that where you should be starting.

Comment: but yes the expression `not ns.nil?` will evaluate to true or false.